# finding the difference between 2 arrays of type dbms_utility.lname_array in PLSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I am currently on version ORACLE 10g.

I need to find the difference in the elements between 2 arrays. 
(Note: the arrays are of type dbms_utility.lname_array)

Below is the example.

In the below example i need to find the element in 1st array which is not in the 2nd array. (element 3 in l_new_array is not present in l_old_array)

```
declare
l_new_array dbms_utility.lname_array;
l_old_array dbms_utility.lname_array;
g_new varchar2(200) := '1,2,3,4';
g_old varchar2(200) := '1,2,4,5';
l_new_count binary_integer;
l_old_count binary_integer;
begin
 dbms_utility.comma_to_table(
                        list   => regexp_replace(g_new,'(^|,)','\1x'),
                        tablen => l_new_count,
                        tab    => l_new_array
                    );
dbms_utility.comma_to_table(
                        list   => regexp_replace(g_old,'(^|,)','\1x'),
                        tablen => l_old_count,
                        tab    => l_old_array
                    );
dbms_output.put_line (l_new_array-l_old_array);
if (l_new_array <> l_old_array) then
    dbms_output.put_line ('if');
else
    dbms_output.put_line ('else');
end if;
end;
```

Comment: When you say 'not present', do you mean it isn't present at all, or isn't in that position? i.e. what would you want to see if `g_old` was `''1,2,4,3'`. with all the same elements but in a different order?

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the arrays and compare their elements. I'm not sure if you want the generic if/else too so I'll include both parts, as a starting point for you to adapt to what you need to see:

```
declare
...
l_different boolean := false;
begin
dbms_utility.comma_to_table(...);
dbms_utility.comma_to_table(...);

if l_new_count != l_old_count then
    l_different := true;
    dbms_output.put_line('Different sizes (' || l_new_array.count
        ||'/'|| l_old_array.count ||')');
else
    for i in 1..l_new_count loop
        if l_new_array(i) != l_old_array(i) then
            l_different := true;
            dbms_output.put_line('Mismatch at position ' || i || ': '
                || l_old_array(i) || ' => ' || l_new_array(i));
            exit;
        end if;
    end loop;
end if;

if l_different then
    dbms_output.put_line ('if');
else
    dbms_output.put_line ('else');
end if;
end;
/
```

which gets output:

```
Mismatch at position 3: x4 => x3
if

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

The `l_different` is only there to do the final if/else, and if you don't want that - just the 'mismatch' message is enough - then you don't need to declare, set or use that.

You may want to handle different lengths differently, at least if new has more elements than old, but again it's a starting point for you to work from.

Comment: Thank you Alex. 
Yes i have done the looping now. But I was wondering if there is any direct comparison functions available for this operation other than looping.

Comment: Not really with that collection type. There are other options [for nested tables](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm#i36377), but you are using associative arrays.

Comment: Hi Alex. 
Is there  a way to convert my array type (dbms_utility.lname_array) into nested tables other than looping ?
@Alex Poole.